# AIML pattern for singluar and plural

Tags: aiml

I would like to know how to handle both singular and plural to match the same pattern.

Ex: “**get Statement**” and “**get Statement*s***”

```
 <category>
       <pattern>get Statement</pattern>
       <template>Please get it from:</template>
 </category>

 <category>
       <pattern>get Statements</pattern>
       <template>Please get it from:</template>
 </category>
```

I want to show the same result **without** writing two **separate patterns** and **without** using **SET tag**.

Please advise me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in standard AIML v1 or v2 if you insist on one pattern only. The closest you could get is a pattern GET * which matches both cases, but that is too general to be very useful. ***If*** you were happy to use two patterns, you could do this:

```
 <category>
       <pattern>GET STATEMENT</pattern>
       <template><srai>GET STATEMENTS</srai></template>
 </category>

 <category>
       <pattern>GET STATEMENTS</pattern>
       <template>Please get it from:</template>
 </category>
```

Your custom logic is confined to one place (the plural GET STATEMENTS pattern), and the singular pattern calls the plural pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's very late now so probably you have found the answer, but in Program-Y you can write it as...

```
<pattern>get <regex pattern="STATEMEN[T|TS]" /></pattern>
<template>Please get it from:</template>
```